# Sync interceptor for modifying documents before send to server or persist to disk?

Tags: pouchdb

Is it possible to hook into sync events so that I can:

- perform actions on incoming documents during a sync before they are persisted locally
- perform actions on outgoing documents before they are sent to the remote server during a sync

The use case I'm thinking of is encryption/decryption for specific fields of documents so they are stored encrypted on the server but unencrypted locally on the device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [transform-pouch](https://github.com/nolanlawson/transform-pouch).